# hold off showing image until fully loaded in html result via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know a lot of questions have been asked about this question but i am still not abale to get my head round it.
I have a number of images that when clicked, i get the big image via ajax. The result from ajax a load of html that goes into my chosen div. the reason for this is that i plan on using other information on the page that ajax returns.
The html that gets returned contains the img tag and i am wanting hold off showing the image until it is fully loaded.
here is what i have so far:

```
function getimage(sent_data){
$("#gallery").hide()
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "gallery/name.php?",
        data: "id=" + sent_data,
        success: callback
    });
}
function callback(data, status){
         $("#gallery").html('').hide(); // you need to remove the old image
        $("#gallery").removeClass("loading").html(data).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

and the data returned is:

```
<a href="test.jpg" class = "cloud-zoom" rel="position: 'inside' , showTitle: false, adjustX:-4, adjustY:-4">
    <img src="test.jpg" width="450" height="301" alt="johnboy"/></a>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but this should work.

when you get your html data from your server place the returned html but not show, then add load handler to your gallery element and when it loads show your html.

```
$("#gallery").load(function(e) {
    $(this).show();
});

function callback(data, status){
     //edit: you must place your returned data
     $("#gallery").html(data).hide(); // you need to remove the old image
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have added the code but #gallery isn't updated at all. Ajax is still returning the html but not placing it inside the div.

Comment: Do i still need to have the line .html(data)?
@jsonx

Comment: Yes, you must place your returned data. I have edited the code.